# Removing field from form

Tags: users, forms, i18n-l10n

I just came across a [solution](https://drupal.org/node/1029486) regarding media module.
It suggested that:

replace all

```
unset($form[$id]);
```

to

```
$form[$id] = array('#language' => NULL);
```

in media_gallery.module

This worked nicely for my problem, but I do not understand what it actually does.
The unset is used when we want to remove a field from a form, fx when someone does not have access to the form.
Is the 2nd equivalent of the 1st?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first statement essentially removes a field from the form. The second statement sets the field's language to undefined (neutral). They are not the same, but they both help you to deal with this module's issue as they both prevent the form from passing invalid keys to `locale_field_node_form_submit()`.

Comment: Worth noting that using `unset` on form fields can be a bad thing (if you're using it in a form alter for example), as there may be logic in validate/submit handlers that relies on those array keys existing.